# How to cleanup files before the build?

Tags: teamcity

I need to remove all files that aren't present in VCS before the build; I've tried setting the "Clean files policy:All untracked files" option, but the binary and zip files created by the previous build remain.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Build Files Cleaner (Swabra) under Build Features Section. It can help you removing any locking files as well.

[image]